# Struts2 validation with BigDecimal

Tags: validation, struts2

In my database I have changed the type of a field from VARCHAR to DECIMAL. Therefore I have change the type in the java model class from String to BigDecimal.

In my previous XML validation file I have a requiredString fieldValidator. If I leave it, everytime I enter the value (a big decimal) in the form field, the requiredString fieldValidator fires.  (maybe a problem with the param interceptor that should convert String to BigDecimal).

Anyway for the same field, I have another field validator which is a REGEX.

So I thought that if I dont use the requieredString, just the regex validator it would work, but not. If i dont fill the field up, no error fires.

So.. to sum up :

my action has a field from the Beneficiary class.
In the Beneficiairy class I have a BigDecimal field.
my xml validation file is like that for this field :

```
<field name="benef.nirBenef">
    <field-validator type="regex">
        <param name="expression"><![CDATA[^(1|2)\d{14}$]]></param>
        <message key="error.securityNumber"/>
    </field-validator>
```

when the field is empty, the validation says it is all right.

why ?

when if I use the requiredstring validator, the validation says it is wrong even though the value is good

Thank you

Comment: well, first I can use required validator instead of requieredString

Comment: second, I have to create a class that extends DefaultTypeConverter to be sure that Param interceptor does his job

Comment: but still it looks like my regex validator does not work anymore... so this is the question now

Comment: the question is  : why regex validator does not work when the field is a BigDecimal, knowing that I used class converter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it...it is the same thing for any objects..

*/ Create a file saying what field(s) is/are complex
Name of the file : name_of_the_action-conversion.properties

for example my action class is BenefInfos.java, so my properties file is : BenefInfos-conversion.properties

```
benef.nirBenef=model.BigDecimalConverter
benef.nirAssure=model.BigDecimalConverter
```

the value is the name of my converter class BigDecimalConverter in model package

*/ Create BigDecimalConverter.java

```
public class BigDecimalConverter extends DefaultTypeConverter {

@Override
public Object convertValue(Map Context, Object values, Class classe) {
    BigDecimal field = null;

    if(classe == BigDecimal.class) {
        String value = ((String[]) values)[0];
        field = new BigDecimal(value);
    }

    return field;
}
```

}

*/Now if you want to VALIDATE, you have to create your own validator. To do so :

*/ add validators.xml to declare your own validator :

```
<validators>
    <validator name="socialsecurityformat" 
        class="validator.SocialSecurityValidator"
    />
</validators>
```

*/Create the validator class (here it is SocialSecurityValidator)

```
public class SocialSecurityValidator extends FieldValidatorSupport{
  public void validate(Object o) throws ValidationException {
    String fieldName = this.getFieldName();

    if(this.getFieldValue(fieldName, o) != null) {
        String value = ((BigDecimal)this.getFieldValue(fieldName, o)).toString();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(1|2|7)\\d{14}$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(value);

        if(!m.matches()) {
            addFieldError(fieldName, o);
        }
    }
  }
```

}

*/ and finally in the validation xml file you use your own validator.

```
<field name="benef.nirBenef">
    <field-validator type="required">
        <message key="error.requiredField"/>
    </field-validator>
    <field-validator type="socialsecurityformat">
        <message key="error.securityNumber"/>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Hope this is helpful